# Почему не работает авторизация GooglePlay Games в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, google-play-games

Я сделал все верно, в Google API указал SHA1, Связал всё это с Google Console, вставил ресурсы и Web Client ID в Unity, но каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь авторизоваться пишет "Canceled".

В LogCat я не получаю ошибок, есть только:

```
*** [Play Games Plugin 0.11.01] 02.18.23 ERROR: Returning an error code
GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject:Update()
Google Play services out of date for iae.perfectray.dogs. Reqires 21300000 but found 212621032
```

Вот код авторизации:

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Auth : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public Text text;
    void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    }
    public void Authh()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(ProccessAuth);
    }
    internal void ProccessAuth(SignInStatus status)
    {
        if(status == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            text.text = "Status: Succesfull";
            
        }
        else
        {
            text.text = "Status: " + status;
         
            
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Та же самая ошибка, авторизация работала до добавления в игру облачных сохранений, сейчас в поисках решения сам, удалось вам что-нибудь отыскать для решения этой проблемы ?